# Skip specific validator function in pydantic during test

Tags: mocking, pytest, pydantic, pytest-mock

I have a Pydantic `BaseModel` class that uses a validator method to go through a checklist before executing a command:

```py
class Command(BaseModel):
    path: Path

    @validator("path")
    def check_env(val):
        if not val.exists():
           raise AttributeError
        if not path / os.environ.get("FOO"):
           raise AttributeError
        ...
        # Check some other necessary environment variables
        return val

    def execute():
        subprocess.run(...)
```

Since the execution of the command is quite lengthy, during test runs, I usually mock it (I have a non-mocking version for release testing).
What I'm trying to do is to mock the validator, as when testing since I'm not really running the command, I have no need for the environment variables to be set.

For the moment I added a `skip_check_env` boolean value with a default of `False` which I toggle to true for testing purposes. But I don't like it as it could be misused and it's hackish to insert testing code into the actual production code.

So how can I mock pydantic's call to `check_env` telling it to return the value it received?

I tried specifying a `side_effect` but for some reason, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is not that simple with Pydantic model validators because they are registered by the metaclass upon model definition.

You could of course mess around with the `__validators__` class attribute. Since it is a dictionary with keys corresponding to the validated model fields, you could temporarily remove the "path" validator from it before your test. Though I haven't tried that and don't know, whether that will have additional implications.

But maybe I am too pragmatic in this case. I would just simply factor out those costly steps from the validator into its own class method and have the validator call it. Then you can easily mock that costly method in your tests and keep the validator method otherwise untouched. Seems to me to be the easier approach. Here is a little demo.

`code.py`

```py
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep                                                                                          from pydantic import BaseModel, validator               


class Command(BaseModel):
    path: Path

    @classmethod
    def do_costly_stuff(cls, path: Path) -> None:
        sleep(30)
        print(cls, path)

    @validator("path")
    def validate_path(cls, path: Path) -> Path:
        cls.do_costly_stuff(path)
        return path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This will take a while...")
    print(Command(path="foo/bar"))
```

---

`test.py`

```py
from pathlib import Path
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code


class CommandTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch.object(code.Command, "do_costly_stuff")
    def test_init(self, mock_do_costly_stuff: MagicMock) -> None:
        obj = code.Command(path="foo/bar")
        expected_path = Path("foo/bar")
        self.assertEqual(expected_path, obj.path)
        mock_do_costly_stuff.assert_called_once_with(expected_path)
```

While the `code` script takes the full 30 seconds to complete, the test is passed almost immediately.