# How can I mock pydantic validators in unit tests?

Tags: python, list, unit-testing, pytest, pydantic

I"m trying to mock a validator in a unit test, I just want to see if the validator was called, however my patch path does not seem to be correct, I tried many variation but the one used here should be ok, yet it is not.

project structure :

[image]

awx_models.py :

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator

class Playbook(BaseModel):
    url: str = Field(title="the url")

    @validator('url')
    def validate_playbook_url(cls, value):
        if value == "titi":
            raise Exception("should have been toto")
        return value
```

test_awx_models.py:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.models.awx_models import Playbook

@patch("src.models.awx_models.Playbook.validate_playbook_url")
def test_that_validator_is_called(mock_validate_playbook_url):
    Playbook(url="toto")
    mock_validate_playbook_url.assert_called_once()
```

test results :

```
Launching pytest with arguments C:/checkout2/test_unit_test/test/unit/src/models/test_awx_models.py --no-header --no-summary -q in C:\checkout2\test_unit_test\test\unit\src\models

============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_awx_models.py::test_that_validator_is_called FAILED                 [100%]
test_awx_models.py:4 (test_that_validator_is_called)
mock_validate_playbook_url = <MagicMock name='validate_playbook_url' id='2306368451080'>

    @patch("src.models.awx_models.Playbook.validate_playbook_url")
    def test_that_validator_is_called(mock_validate_playbook_url):
        Playbook(url="toto")
>       mock_validate_playbook_url.assert_called_once()

test_awx_models.py:8: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

_mock_self = <MagicMock name='validate_playbook_url' id='2306368451080'>

    def assert_called_once(_mock_self):
        """assert that the mock was called only once.
        """
        self = _mock_self
        if not self.call_count == 1:
            msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called once. Called %s times." %
                   (self._mock_name or 'mock', self.call_count))
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'validate_playbook_url' to have been called once. Called 0 times.

C:\Python36\lib\unittest\mock.py:795: AssertionError


============================== 1 failed in 0.11s ==============================
```

this is just a small test project to try to find out what the issue is, in reallity I have massive pydantic object with a tons of validators. those validator are externalized in function in validators.py files.

We are testing the behavior of those validator and then in the tests of the models we just want to check that our validator are called without them actually running.

In that way we don't have to build 20 version of the models to test the validator behaviors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock **Pydantic** validators with **unittest**, as far as I know, as that logic relies on the metaclass behaviour, hence you would have to mess around with the code at that level and monkey patch manually.

See [ModelMetaClass](https://class%20ModelMetaclass(ABCMeta):) (for V1, which I assume you are using still since you use the `@validator` decorator), or [ModelMetaclass](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py#L59) (for V2).

Following this comment:

> this is just a small test project to try to find out what the issue
> is, in reallity I have massive pydantic object with a tons of
> validators. those validator are externalized in function in
> validators.py files.

Here is a proposed solution that patches that external validation logic, assuming you have a `validators` module (`src/validators/validators.py`).

```
.
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── awx_models.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── validators
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── validators.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_awx_models.py
```

**Code:**

`awx_models.py`

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator
from src.validators import validators


class Playbook(BaseModel):
    url: str = Field(title="the url")

    @validator('url')
    def validate_playbook_url(cls, value):
        return validators.do_external_validation(value)
```

`validators.py`

```
# A bunch of functions/classes like this.
def do_external_validation(value):
    if value == "titi":
        raise Exception("should have been toto")
    return value
```

`test_awx_models.py`

```
import pytest
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from src.validators import validators
from src.models import awx_models


class TestUrlValidator(TestCase):
    @patch.object(validators, "do_external_validation")
    def test_patched_url_validator(self, mock_do_external_validation: MagicMock) -> None:
        expected_url = "foo"
        mock_do_external_validation.return_value = expected_url
        obj = awx_models.Playbook(url="titi")
        assert expected_url == obj.url
        mock_do_external_validation.assert_called_once_with("titi")

    def test_url_validator(self) -> None:
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
            _ = awx_models.Playbook(url="titi")
        assert str(excinfo.value) == "should have been toto"
```

**Note:** This would also work for class methods, so you could take the validation logic out of the **Pydantic** validators, put it in class methods and then mock those with **unittest**. Here is a similar answer following that approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73896933/13500362